# Move car forward to rotated direction

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simple JavaScript project to move a car in a particular direction in order to bolster my knowledge about game development.

I have added a feature to make the car rotate in a 360 degree motion. However I cannot get the car to move in said direction. How do I fix this?

I've loaded the code here: https://plnkr.co/edit/J9737Y0l6GuDb94c

Car rotation code:

```
Game._rotate = function (moveAngle, direction) {
  switch (direction) {
    case 'UP':
      Car.angleInDegrees = 0;
      break;
    case 'RIGHT':
      Car.angleInDegrees += moveAngle;
      break;
    case 'DOWN':
      Car.angleInDegrees = 180;
      break;
    case 'LEFT':
      Car.angleInDegrees += moveAngle;
      break;
  }
  this.car.angle = Car.angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);
}
```

Car movement code:

```
Game.update = function (delta) {
  // var dirx = 0;
  // var diry = 0;

  if (Keyboard.isDown(Keyboard.LEFT)) {
    Car.moveAngle = 1
    this._rotate(Car.moveAngle, Car.left)
  }
  else if (Keyboard.isDown(Keyboard.RIGHT)) {
    Car.moveAngle = -1
    this._rotate(Car.moveAngle, Car.right)
  }
  else if (Keyboard.isDown(Keyboard.UP)) {
    accelerate();
  }
  // else if (Keyboard.isDown(Keyboard.DOWN)) {
  //   this._rotate(dirx, Car.down)
  //   diry = accelerate(diry, Car.backward);
  // }
  else {
    decelerate();
  }

  this.car.move(delta, Car.moveAngle, 0);
  this.camera.update();
};

function accelerate() {
  Car.acceleration += 1;
  if (Car.speed >= 0) {
    if (Car.speed < Car.maxSpeed) {
      Car.speed += Car.acceleration;
    }
  }
}

function decelerate() {
  if (Car.speed > 0) {
    Car.speed = Car.speed - Car.friction;
  }

  if (Car.acceleration > 0) {
    Car.acceleration = Car.acceleration - Car.friction;
  }

  if (Car.speed < 0) {
    Car.speed = 0;
  }

  if (Car.acceleration < 0) {
    Car.acceleration = 0;
  }
}
```

Currently this is what happens (I attempted to rotate and then pressed the up key)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through trial and error, and with the help of [game dev stack exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/117996/how-does-this-math-behind-converting-angles-to-vectors-work), here is one solution:

```
Car.prototype.move = function () {
  var angle = Car.angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180
  this.x -= 2 * Math.sin(angle);
  this.y += 2 * Math.cos(angle);
};
```

```
Game.update = function () {
  if (Keyboard.isDown(Keyboard.LEFT)) {
    Car.moveAngle = 1
    this._rotate(Car.moveAngle, Car.left)
  }
  else if (Keyboard.isDown(Keyboard.RIGHT)) {
    Car.moveAngle = -1
    this._rotate(Car.moveAngle, Car.right)
  }
  else if (Keyboard.isDown(Keyboard.UP)) {
    this.car.move();
  }
  else if (Keyboard.isDown(Keyboard.DOWN)) {
    this.car.move();
  }
  else {
    decelerate();
  }
  this.camera.update();
};
```

Full code here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ekkm0hbu5PbNWwjM